# how to retrieve data from a node.js file with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, twilio

I'm new to nodejs and trying to figure out how to get twilio data from a working node script via ajax on the front end.

I have this on the backend

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const twilio = require('twilio');

const accountSid = '####';
const authToken = "####";
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

const baseURL = 'https://api.twilio.com'
const recordingExtension = '.mp3' //mp3 or wav

let app = express();

app.post('/list', (request, response) => {
  const recordings =[]
  client.recordings.list(function(err, data) {
      data.recordings.forEach(function(recording) {
          var recordingURIComponent = recording.uri.replace('.json','')
          var recordingURL = baseURL + recordingURIComponent + recordingExtension
          recordings.push(recordingURL)
      });
      const recordingData = {
        recordings: recordings
      }
      response.send(recordingData)
  });
});


app.listen(3000, '127.0.0.1',function(){
  console.log('listening');
});
```

and now I want to access that response from ajax on the front end.

I know it could look something like:

```
$.post( '/list', function(data) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

But I'm not sure where to direct my post/get/ajax to. If both files are on the same server, what URL do I use as the post request? Do I need to specify the port (3000?). Or do I need to do something in express to serve up the html file that will do the ajax request?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The route isn't configured to accept any parameters. But your jQuery post is passing parameters? Why is it like that?

Comment: My bad - no params needed. Modified code.

Comment: Not versed with the twilio api but what is `client.recordings.list()` doing? And what is the response of `$.post()` you are seeing in the console?

Comment: Just getting a 404 not found for the `$.post` - the client.recording.list just lists out all of the recordings that are available in my twilio account. It works on its own if I execute it solely with a node.js command in its own file on my server, but not sure how to call it from this `app.post('/list') command

Comment: Resolve the 404 issue first. Use cURL or [other means](https://superuser.com/questions/344927/powershell-equivalent-of-curl) to issue a request to that endpoint. Also check with the web console and the node.js console (if logging is enabled) to identify what request hit the express server.

Comment: I think that's what I'm trying to resolve here is the 404 - I don't actually know what the proper endpoint should be? Do I need to do a post to port 3000? To the name of the file? In twilio, using a local server, the docs suggest using ngrok to create an http server to localhost. So I just do ngrok http 3000, and it gives me back a URL. I add my route to that URL, and the twilio stuff works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by having node.js also serve up my static html:

`app.use(express.static('public_html'))`

I changed to a get request:

```
$.ajax({
   method: "GET",
   url: "/list"
})
 .done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data)
    playlist = data
    len = playlist.recordings.length
    $audio[0].addEventListener('ended',onAudioEnded);
    playAudio()
});
```

and

`app.get('/list', (request, response) => {`

With this folder structure:

```
/
  app.js

  public_html/

    index.html
```

and made sure to access my site from:

`http://[mysite].com:3000`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do post request like this

```
$.ajax({
      url: "/list",
      data:{'auth':'465dsfsd5f44654'},
      type: "POST",
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      success: function (data) {

      }
  });
```